# Why doesn't gnome extension update and keeps prompting?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

When Im on the https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ page and click on an update button for an extension (clipboard indicator), it toggles the extension off. When I then try to toggle it back on, it promts me with a message asking if the extension update should be installed. Clicking `install` does not do anything, at least visually.

A little later (normally after a boot) the same thing keeps happening, without ever an installed update. Im not sure how to just install it for once and all. Any ideas?

Comment: Try uninstalling the GNOME extension and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179421/why-can-i-not-update-gnome-to-version-3-34) problem.

The issue was to

```
flatpak repair
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08
flatpak update
```

This also let me install `org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264`. Haven't encountered the problem again.